# Laravel 5.4 Saving an array of input to a belongsto model

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

```
  <input type="text" name="subcat[0]">
   <input type="text" name="subcat[1]">
   <input type="text" name="subcat[2]">
   <input type="text" name="subcat[3]">
```

these are my models:

In the category Model

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory','subcategories_id');
}
```

SubCategory Model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category' ,'categories_id');
}
```

Controller

```
$s = Input::get('subcat');
$input = request('category');
$id = Category::where('CategoryName', $input)->pluck('id');

$subcat = [];



         $category=Category::find($id );


    foreach ($s as $item ) {
    $item->category()->associate($category); 
    $item->save();
    }
```

I'm getting an error "Call to a member function category() on string:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$item` is the string from your input (I guess it must be the name of the sub category). You should create the subcategory first.

I think you should replace:

```
foreach ($s as $item ) {
    $item->category()->associate($category); 
    $item->save();
}
```

By:

```
foreach ($s as $item) {

    // Get sub category by name or create a new subcategory

    $sub_cat = SubCategory::where('SubCategoryName', $item)->first();

    if (!$sub_cat) {
        $sub_cat = new \App\SubCategory();
        $sub_cat-> SubCategoryName = $item; // <-- replace "SubCategoryName" by 
                                            //     the property you need
                                            //     to update from input

        $sub_cat->save();
    }        
    $category->subcategories()->save($sub_cat);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My primary mistake was that I wasn't even creating a new object

Answer (score 0):

`$s` is array of strings.
Your for loop can be written as

```
foreach ($s as $item ) {
    $sub = SubCategory::where('SubCategoryName', $item)->first();
    $sub->category()->associate($category); 
    $sub->save();
}
```